# How to append a document to existing document in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query

I wrote a python script to parse Apache logs and store it in mongodb in the following format :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("589e77cf74eea90879f49c80"),
    "http_version": "HTTP/1.1",
    "time": ISODate("2017-02-11T02:32:46Z"),
    "server_ip": "x.x.x.x",
    "method": "GET",
    "content_length": 529,
    "referral": "-",
    "uri": "/xxxxxxx.sdsd",
    "agent": "Mozilla/5.00 (Nikto/2.1.5) (Evasions:None) (Test:map_codes)",
    "status_code": 404
}
```

I need to find the count of 404, 200 and 302 requests per IP address. I wrote one more script to fetch the values and store it in a dictionary. However, the script takes like 2 min to fetch the results.

```
db=conn.http_bank
resp= db.http_bank.distinct("server_ip")
total_count=db.http_bank.find().count()
print total_count

def status_code(db,i):

dict_status_code={}
dict_status_code[i]={}
dict_status_code[i].update({'200':db.http_bank.find({"server_ip":i,"status_code":200}).count()})
dict_status_code[i].update({'404':db.http_bank.find({"server_ip":i,"status_code":404}).count()})
dict_status_code[i].update({'302':db.http_bank.find({"server_ip":i,"status_code":302}).count()})

print dict_status_code

print status_code(db,"x.x.x.x")
```

Do I need to change my Python code logic or Should I change the way I store the data in MongoDB?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to group `status_code` and then retrieve an array with the counting for each group `status_code`/`server_ip`. In mongoDB shell it would be :

```
db.http_bank.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "status_code": "$status_code",
            "server_ip": "$server_ip"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "_id.status_code": { "$in": [200, 302, 404] }
    }
}])
```

which gives :

```
{ "_id" : { "status_code" : 404, "server_ip" : "1.1.1.1" }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "status_code" : 302, "server_ip" : "3.3.3.3" }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "status_code" : 200, "server_ip" : "1.1.1.1" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "status_code" : 302, "server_ip" : "2.2.2.2" }, "count" : 1 }
```

In python you can do like [this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html) :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

db = MongoClient().testDB

pipeline = [
    {
        "$match":
        {
            "time":
            {
                "$gte": datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00),
                "$lte": datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00)
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "status_code": "$status_code", 
                "server_ip": "$server_ip"
            }, 
            "count": { 
                "$sum": 1 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id.status_code": { 
                "$in" : [200,302,404] 
            }
        }
    }
]

res = list(db.http_bank.aggregate(pipeline))

dict_status_code={}
dict_status_code[1]={}

for i, val in enumerate(res):

    data = {
        str(int(val["_id"]["status_code"])) : val["count"]
    }
    key = val["_id"]["server_ip"]
    print key, " ==> ", data
```

giving :

```
1.1.1.1  ==>  {'404': 2}
3.3.3.3  ==>  {'302': 2}
1.1.1.1  ==>  {'200': 1}
2.2.2.2  ==>  {'302': 1}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. It was 3 minutes previously. Now it takes 50 sec to fetch all the data.

Comment: 50 seconds is still very slow for such a basic query make sure to check my answer.

Comment: I have like 400K documents in a single collection.

Comment: @Bertrand Martel
resp= db.http_bank.distinct("server_ip")
    for ip in resp:
          ##logic you have mentioned

Comment: I've updated my post matching your requirement eg to group by `server_ip` and  `status_code`. You don't need to loop on `distinct` `server_ip` anymore with this. I leave to you the population of your dict `dict_status_code` with the results

Comment: @BertrandMartel 
Everything is fine now and it just takes a sec to fetch the data.

Comment: @BertrandMartel I am stuck with one more thing, I need to fetch all those records within a specified date range.
I am storing the date for each record too in the database. I tried matching it by date by adding one more line in match block as less than the current date. It just fetches the empty result. 
I cannot post the code for it as this comment section makes it so clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any index on your collection? If not then that is why it is running slow. You can create one in the shell like this:

```
db.http_bank.createIndex({ server_ip: 1, status_code: 1 })
```

This can take a while depending on the size of your collection.

By the way, you should use the aggregation framework like the other answer suggests, but you will need the index either way so create that first.